# How do I iterate over an entire MongoDB collection using mongojs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript, iterator, mongojs

I'm using `mongojs` and I'm trying to iterate over all elements in a collection

```
index = 0

db.keys.find({}, {uid: 1, _id: 0}).forEach((err, key) =>
    if err?
        console.log err
    else 
        console.log (++index) + " key: " + key_uid
```

which logs

```
1 key: bB0KN
2 key: LOtOL
3 key: 51xJM
4 key: x9wFP
5 key: hcJKP
6 key: QZxnE
.
.
.
96 key: EeW6E
97 key: wqfmM
98 key: LIGHK
99 key: bjWTI
100 key: 2zNGE
101 key: F71mL
```

and then stops. However when I log into mongo from the terminal and run

```
> db.keys.count()
2317381
```

So clearly it should be returning a lot more keys. Do you have any ideas what could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the `each()` method, not `forEach()`. forEach() is going to iterate over every document in the batch - as you've discovered this defaults to 101. each() will iterate over every document in the cursor. From the documentation:

> **each**
>
> Iterates over all the documents for this cursor. As with
>   {cursor.toArray}, not all of the elements will be iterated if this
>   cursor had been previouly accessed. In that case, {cursor.rewind} can
>   be used to reset the cursor. However, unlike {cursor.toArray}, the
>   cursor will only hold a maximum of batch size elements at any given
>   time if batch size is specified. Otherwise, the caller is responsible
>   for making sure that the entire result can fit the memory.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html

Example code:

```
// Grab a cursor
      var cursor = collection.find();

      // Execute the each command, triggers for each document
      cursor.each(function(err, item) {

        // If the item is null then the cursor is exhausted/empty and closed
        if(item == null) {

          // Show that the cursor is closed
          cursor.toArray(function(err, items) {
            assert.ok(err != null);

            // Let's close the db
            db.close();
          });
        };
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing only first 101 documents because that's the default number of documents MongoDB driver fetched from the server in the first [batch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-batches).

> For most queries, the first batch returns 101 documents or just enough
>   documents to exceed 1 megabyte. Subsequent batch size is 4 megabytes.

You can try to use `find` and then iterate over documents.

```
coll.find({}, {uid:1, _id : 0}, function(err, docs){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    docs.forEach(function(doc, index) { 
        console.log(index + " key: " + doc.uid) 
    });
});
```