# Loop through data in batches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a data set of dates and I'd like to check if a user input date clashes with an existing one,
so far this has been my approach:

```
for await (const doc of collection.find(query)) {
 if(check_clash(doc.date, user_date))
   break;
}
```

but I have 2 concerns:

1. Will this work even for a larger data set?
2. Is there any way to do this in batches?
   i.e. since I'm guessing every time 1 doc is fetched it takes some amount of time whereas if we take e.g. 20 docs at a time, compare them & **then** take the next batch it *should* take less amount of time since there are less calls to the database?

maybe a sudo code would look something like this?

```
await collection.find(query).getInBatches(20,(docs)=>{
   for(const d in docs)
     if(check_clash(d.date, user_date))
       return false; // break out 
})
```

P.S. I tried the approach in this question: [Batching data with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786516/what-is-the-faster-way-to-iterate-over-mongo-data-find-in-batch-vs-iterate-with) but a solution pointed out:

> It is never a good idea to use skip in mongo queries

---

**Edit:**

The true nature of my problem is that I have a user input date range and bookings also with a date range as such:

MONTHLY_COLLECTION:

```
{
"month_year" : "01-2020",
"dates" : {
    "1": [...], // array of Booking IDS whose range falls within this date
    "5": [...],
    "28":[...]
},
...
```

BOOKING_COLLECTION

```
{
  "_id": ... , //  Booking ID
 "from": "2023-09-04T04:30:00.000Z",
 "till": "2023-09-05T06:00:00.000Z",
 ...
},

...
```

and my approach has been to first get all the Booking IDs then check if they clash with the user input range as such

```
const user_range_start=new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1) // 01-01-2020
const user_range_end=new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 2, 23) // 23-03-2020

let id_arr = []
await DB.collection(MONTHLY_COLLECTION).find(
    {
        "month_year": {
            "$in": month_year_between(user_range_start, user_range_end) // [`01-2020`, `02-2020`, `03-2020` ]
        }
    }
)
.forEach(doc => {
    for (let date in doc["dates"])
        id_arr.push(...doc["dates"][date])
})


await DB.collection(BOOKING_COLLECTION).find({
    "_id": {
        "$in": id_arr
    }
})
.forEach(doc => {
       if(check_clash(doc.from, doc.till, user_range_start, user_range_end)
          return false
})
```

My only problem with this approach is that it is exhaustive till 101 documents since we might need to check for more than that

I've been looking into `aggregate` but can I stop an aggregate once a clash has been found or will it iterate through all the documents anyways?

Comment: What is the purpose of your check_clash function ? What is the purpose of this script ?
Iterating over the results of query and adding js is not the way if you try to find a doc that match an input date. You probably should use a find or aggregate function, but we would need more details about what you're trying to achieve, to help you best.

Comment: @Fourchette I've edited the question to exactly match my problem could you please take a look?

Comment: "_it is exhaustive till 101 documents_" - what makes you say that?

Comment: @user20042973 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215021/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-entire-mongodb-collection-using-mongojs)